# What is the Stack Exchange podcast intro music?

Tags: discussion, podcast

The podcast intro music sounds like a bass fiddle.  Was it written for the podcast or taken from an album? If taken from an album, what album?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is the tune ["Faster Does It"](http://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/index.html?isrc=USUAN1100794) by Kevin MacLeod, available on [incompetech.com](http://incompetech.com/), which has music available under a Creative Commons license.

Comment: Yep - you got it exactly right @Bart.  Curious how you knew that?

Comment: @AlexMiller A good guess really. Probably free music, something jazzy, let's try incompetech. Bingo. I've used that site before and thought there was a good chance it came from there.